# Timeline getting data from database

Tags: json, html-table, datasource, timeline

Timeglider is a timeline project.
[Timeglider](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/timeglider-impressive-jquery-plugin-for-data-driven-timelines/) is a jQuery plugin for displaying any number of events in a highly-flexible timeline.

One of the easiest way for fetching and reading data is using a [TABLE](http://timeglider.com/jquery/?p=table).
this TABLE is a HTML TABLE that have a specific properties
for example we should create table with its data in SQL.

I use the objects like GRIDVIEW or (TABLE and panel) but these are not have those tags.

please help me
may i use json datasource? but i dont know how?
but with table it is easier.

> Timeglider timelines can load directly from data you provide in an
>   HTML table.

may i use with `response.write` ? or another proposed way?
or add hese line to table. (i know only gridview have property header) but table doesnt??!!!!
please help me.

```
<!-- The first row of the table is reserved for meta-data.

     Class values below are *critical* for mapping out data from the 
     <td> elements that follow ---  though order is not important.
     The text in <td> elements is *not* critical: just the class names.
-->
<tr>
  <th class="tg-startdate">start date</th>
  <th class="tg-enddate">end date</th>
  <th class="tg-title">title</th>
  <th class="tg-description">description</th>
  <th class="tg-icon">icon</th>
  <th class="tg-importance">importance</th>
  <th class="tg-link">link</th> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it by creating my desired HTML code and with

```
Response.Write();
```

fire it in the output
and Timeglider is also work good